# How to make sprite (turtle) move through the best path cell by cell

Tags: python, algorithm, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Right now I am creating a maze path finding algorithm using breadth first search. The algorithm to find the 'best path' seems to work. The problem however is that I am not sure how to make the sprite (turtle) move through that best path.

Here is code:

```
import turtle
import time
import sys
from collections import deque

bs = turtle.Screen()
bs.bgcolor("black")
bs.setup(1300,700)

class Building(turtle.Turtle):                             # Define building class
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")                               # Shape of the building
        self.color("grey")                                 # Colour of the building
        self.penup()                                       # Lift the pen up so it does not leave a trail
        self.speed('fast')                                 # Sets the speed that the building is drawn on the screen
        
class Road(turtle.Turtle):                                 # Define road class
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")                               # Shape of the road
        self.color("white")                                # Colour of the road
        self.penup()                                       # Lift the pen up so it does not leave a trail
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed('fast')                                 # Sets the speed that the road is drawn on the screen
        
class Start(turtle.Turtle):                                # Define start class
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")                               # Shape of the start point
        self.color('green')                                # Colour of the start point 
        self.penup()                                       # Lift the pen up so it does not leave a trail
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed('fast')
        
class Route(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("yellow")
        self.penup()
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed('fast')
        
class End(turtle.Turtle):                                  # Define end class
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")                               # Shape of the end point
        self.color("red")                                  # Colour of the end point
        self.penup()                                       # Lift the pen up so it does not leave a trail
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed('fast')    
        
class Searcher(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("white")
        self.penup()
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed('fast')
        
class sprite(turtle.Turtle):                               # Define sprite class
    noOfSteps = 0                                          # Declare variable noOfSteps and instantiate it as 0
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("turtle")                               # Shape of the sprite
        self.color("purple")                               # Colour of the sprite
        self.penup()                                       # Lift the pen up so it does not leave a trail
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed('fast')

    def moveSprite(self):
        start.color('green')
        start.stamp()
        searcher.color('red')
        searcher.stamp()
        self.goto(start_x, start_y)
        self.showturtle()
        # self.goto(solution[x,y])
        
# Read maze txt file
def readMaze(mazeSet, filename):
    mazeFile = open(filename, "r")
    lines = mazeFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        row = [c for c in line]
        mazeSet.append(row)

mazeSet = []  # This declares the maze as an empty list
readMaze(mazeSet, "CA1_Map.txt") # This reads the maze into the list

# Setting up of maze
def setupMaze(mazeSet):
    global start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y
    m_height, m_width = len(mazeSet), len(mazeSet[0])     # Define maze height and maze width

    for y in range(m_height):                             # Select each line in the maze
        for x in range(m_width):                          # Identify each character in the line
            character = mazeSet[y][x]                     # Assign the maze reference to the variable 'character'
            screen_x = ((x - m_width) * 24) + 150         # Assign screen_x to screen starting position for x coords
            screen_y = ((m_width - y) * 24) - 200         # Assign screen_y to screen starting position for y coords

            if character == "X":                          
                building.goto(screen_x, screen_y)         
                building.stamp()                          
                walls.append((screen_x, screen_y))       
                
            if character == "." or character == 'e':      
                path.append((screen_x, screen_y))

            if character == "e":   
                end_x, end_y = screen_x, screen_y
                searcher.color('red')
                searcher.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                searcher.stamp()
                searcher.color('white')
                finish.append((screen_x, screen_y))
                
            if character == "s":
                start_x, start_y = screen_x, screen_y                                  
                start.goto(screen_x,screen_y)
                start.stamp()
    
def search(x,y):
    frontier.append((x, y))
    solution[x,y] = x,y

    while len(frontier) > 0:       
        time.sleep(0)
        x, y = frontier.popleft()     

        if(x - 24, y) in path and (x - 24, y) not in visited:  
            cell = (x - 24, y)
            solution[cell] = x, y   
            frontier.append(cell)  
            visited.add((x-24, y)) 

        if (x, y - 24) in path and (x, y - 24) not in visited: 
            cell = (x, y - 24)
            solution[cell] = x, y
            frontier.append(cell)
            visited.add((x, y - 24))

        if(x + 24, y) in path and (x + 24, y) not in visited:  
            cell = (x + 24, y)
            solution[cell] = x, y
            frontier.append(cell)
            visited.add((x + 24, y))

        if(x, y + 24) in path and (x, y + 24) not in visited:  
            cell = (x, y + 24)
            solution[cell] = x, y
            frontier.append(cell)
            visited.add((x, y + 24))
            
        searcher.goto(x,y)
        searcher.stamp()

def correctRoute(x, y):
    route.goto(x, y)
    route.stamp()
    while (x, y) != (start_x, start_y):    
        route.goto(solution[x, y])     
        route.stamp()
        x, y = solution[x, y]
 
def endProgram():
    bs.exitonclick()
    sys.exit()


# Main program

# Setting up classes
building = Building()
road = Road()
start = Start()
end = End()
searcher = Searcher()
route = Route()
sprite = sprite()

# Setting up lists
walls = []
path = []
finish = []
visited = set()
frontier = deque()
solution = {}                   

setupMaze(mazeSet)
search(start_x, start_y)
correctRoute(end_x, end_y)

while True:
    sprite.moveSprite()
```

The image of the maze currently looks like this:

[image]

So what I need to do is make the purple turtle (kind of hard to see) move from the green square to red square through the best path (yellow squares).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** At the function where the program determines the correct route,
record each coordinate into a list,
and return the list (inverted) so it can be accessed outside the function:

```
def correctRoute(x, y):
    routes = [(x, y)]
    route.goto(x, y)
    route.stamp()
    while (x, y) != (start_x, start_y):    
        route.goto(solution[x, y])     
        route.stamp()
        x, y = solution[x, y]
        routes.append((x, y))
    return routes[::-1]
```

**Step 2:** Give the `moveSprite` function another parameter, and the parameter will be the list of coordinates.
the list will then be split into two parts: the starting coordinates and the path. Before calling `self.showturtle()`,
make sure that the turtle is in its proper starting position first.
Using a `for` loop, loop through the path list with `time.sleep` and make the turtle go to each of the coordinates:

```
def moveSprite(self, routes):
    starting, path = routes[0], routes[1:]
    start.color('green')
    start.stamp()
    searcher.color('red')
    searcher.stamp()
    self.goto(starting)
    self.showturtle()
    for path in path:
        time.sleep(0.3)
        self.goto(path)
```

**Step 3:** At the very bottom of your code, assign the `correctRoute` call to a variable to retrive the coordinates.
Remove the while loop, and put the list of coordinates into the `moveSprite` function:

```
routes = correctRoute(end_x, end_y)

sprite.moveSprite(routes)
```

All together:

```
import turtle
import time
import sys
from collections import deque

bs = turtle.Screen()
bs.bgcolor("black")
bs.setup(1300,700)

class Building(turtle.Turtle):                             # Define building class
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")                               # Shape of the building
        self.color("grey")                                 # Colour of the building
        self.penup()                                       # Lift the pen up so it does not leave a trail
        self.speed('fast')                                 # Sets the speed that the building is drawn on the screen
        
class Road(turtle.Turtle):                                 # Define road class
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")                               # Shape of the road
        self.color("white")                                # Colour of the road
        self.penup()                                       # Lift the pen up so it does not leave a trail
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed('fast')                                 # Sets the speed that the road is drawn on the screen
        
class Start(turtle.Turtle):                                # Define start class
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")                               # Shape of the start point
        self.color('green')                                # Colour of the start point 
        self.penup()                                       # Lift the pen up so it does not leave a trail
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed('fast')
        
class Route(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("yellow")
        self.penup()
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed('fast')
        
class End(turtle.Turtle):                                  # Define end class
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")                               # Shape of the end point
        self.color("red")                                  # Colour of the end point
        self.penup()                                       # Lift the pen up so it does not leave a trail
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed('fast')    
        
class Searcher(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("white")
        self.penup()
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed('fast')
        
class sprite(turtle.Turtle):                               # Define sprite class
    noOfSteps = 0                                          # Declare variable noOfSteps and instantiate it as 0
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.shape("turtle")                               # Shape of the sprite
        self.color("purple")                               # Colour of the sprite
        self.penup()                                       # Lift the pen up so it does not leave a trail
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed('fast')

    def moveSprite(self, routes):
        starting, path = routes[0], routes[1:]
        start.color('green')
        start.stamp()
        searcher.color('red')
        searcher.stamp()
        self.goto(starting)
        self.showturtle()
        for path in path:
            time.sleep(0.3)
            self.goto(path)

# Read maze txt file
def readMaze(mazeSet, filename):
    mazeFile = open(filename, "r")
    lines = mazeFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        row = [c for c in line]
        mazeSet.append(row)

mazeSet = []  # This declares the maze as an empty list
readMaze(mazeSet, "CA1_Map.txt") # This reads the maze into the list

# Setting up of maze
def setupMaze(mazeSet):
    global start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y
    m_height, m_width = len(mazeSet), len(mazeSet[0])     # Define maze height and maze width

    for y in range(m_height):                             # Select each line in the maze
        for x in range(m_width):                          # Identify each character in the line
            character = mazeSet[y][x]                     # Assign the maze reference to the variable 'character'
            screen_x = ((x - m_width) * 24) + 150         # Assign screen_x to screen starting position for x coords
            screen_y = ((m_width - y) * 24) - 200         # Assign screen_y to screen starting position for y coords

            if character == "X":                          
                building.goto(screen_x, screen_y)         
                building.stamp()                          
                walls.append((screen_x, screen_y))       
                
            if character == "." or character == 'e':      
                path.append((screen_x, screen_y))

            if character == "e":   
                end_x, end_y = screen_x, screen_y
                searcher.color('red')
                searcher.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                searcher.stamp()
                searcher.color('white')
                finish.append((screen_x, screen_y))
                
            if character == "s":
                start_x, start_y = screen_x, screen_y                                  
                start.goto(screen_x,screen_y)
                start.stamp()
    
def search(x,y):
    frontier.append((x, y))
    solution[x,y] = x,y

    while len(frontier) > 0:       
        time.sleep(0)
        x, y = frontier.popleft()     

        if(x - 24, y) in path and (x - 24, y) not in visited:  
            cell = (x - 24, y)
            solution[cell] = x, y   
            frontier.append(cell)  
            visited.add((x-24, y)) 

        if (x, y - 24) in path and (x, y - 24) not in visited: 
            cell = (x, y - 24)
            solution[cell] = x, y
            frontier.append(cell)
            visited.add((x, y - 24))

        if(x + 24, y) in path and (x + 24, y) not in visited:  
            cell = (x + 24, y)
            solution[cell] = x, y
            frontier.append(cell)
            visited.add((x + 24, y))

        if(x, y + 24) in path and (x, y + 24) not in visited:  
            cell = (x, y + 24)
            solution[cell] = x, y
            frontier.append(cell)
            visited.add((x, y + 24))
            
        searcher.goto(x,y)
        searcher.stamp()

def correctRoute(x, y):
    routes = [(x, y)]
    route.goto(x, y)
    route.stamp()
    while (x, y) != (start_x, start_y):    
        route.goto(solution[x, y])     
        route.stamp()
        x, y = solution[x, y]
        routes.append((x, y))
    return routes[::-1]
 
def endProgram():
    bs.exitonclick()
    sys.exit()


# Main program

# Setting up classes
building = Building()
road = Road()
start = Start()
end = End()
searcher = Searcher()
route = Route()
sprite = sprite()

# Setting up lists
walls = []
path = []
finish = []
visited = set()
frontier = deque()
solution = {}                   

setupMaze(mazeSet)
search(start_x, start_y)
routes = correctRoute(end_x, end_y)

sprite.moveSprite(routes)
```

If you want the turtle to change its direction at each turn, use this as the `moveSprite` function:

```
    def moveSprite(self, routes):
        starting, routes = routes[0], routes[1:]
        start.color('green')
        start.stamp()
        searcher.color('red')
        searcher.stamp()
        self.goto(starting)
        self.showturtle()
        for path1, path2 in zip(routes, routes[1:]):
            self.goto(path1)
            time.sleep(0.3)
            if path1[0] == path2[0]: # If the x coordinates of two consecutive moves are equal, that means that the turtle is moving along the `y` axis
                if path1[1] > path2[1]:
                    self.setheading(270)
                else:
                    self.setheading(90)
            else: # If the x coordinates of two consecutive moves aren't equal, that means that the turtle is moving along the `x` axis
                if path1[0] > path2[0]:
                    self.setheading(180)
                else:
                    self.setheading(0)
        self.goto(path2)
```